# pass custom value in WCF context between IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest and IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest

Tags: wcf

I have an ASP application which is client of WCF SERVICE1 , which is client of WCF SERVICE2.

I have added IDispatchMessageInspector and IClientMessageInspector to WCF SERVICE1.

Now I need to pass a custom value from ASP to WCF1 , then to WCF2.

from ASP to WCF1 it is trivial , via Message Headers.

The question is , how to pass a custom value from IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(request from ASP received by WCF1) to IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(prepare to send request to WCF2) operation of WCF SERVICE 1 ?

Is there is some context which could be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your code look like? Assuming that first Dispatch Message Inspector is the one making the request to WCF2, then simply using message properties would suffice.

However, if your dispatch message inspector does something; then the request continues processing and it is the service implementation that actually calls WCF2, then you'll need to jump through a few more hoops. In general, I'd say you'd need the inspector to put some data in the service request message properties that the *service* implementation would need to pick up and copy to the message to send to WCF2 so that the client inspector can pick them up.

That's ugly, and would kinda make the whole process more brittle.

Can you elaborate a bit more what you're trying to do? What kind of data are you hoping to pass around this way?

Comment: I need to pass a custom header from asp to wcf2 via wcf1 . actually I need to pass a GUID .

Comment: I haven't tried it; but I think it could be possible to put an ICallContextInitializer on the WCF1 service end that grabs the custom header, puts it into Thread-local-storage, then have the Client inspector grab the value from TLS and copy it to the outgoing message for WCF2.

Comment: There's a good tutorial on using [ThreadStatic] here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/07/18/670497.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to identify and log nested service calls requested by client.
To do that, I stamp each service call by ThreadStatic property and add this property to the header of client call(service1 count as client for service2) than in AfterReceiveRequest method I have checked its existance. If exists,current method was requested by parent service.

```
  public class GenericMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static string _masterServiceGUID;


        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            if (request.Headers.Action == null)
                return null;


            //Control request header for nested call
            string masterRequestId = string.Empty;
            var IsMasterExist = request.Headers.FindHeader("MasterServiceGUID", "namespace");

            if (IsMasterExist > -1)
            {
                //requested by internal service
                masterRequestId = request.Headers.GetReaderAtHeader(IsMasterExist).ReadInnerXml();
            }

        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_masterServiceGUID))
            {
                request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("MasterServiceGUID", "namespace", _masterServiceGUID));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```